# Unable to copy a URL from an excel cell and send it to a webpage

Tags: html, excel, send, excel-reader

Unable to copy a long URL from Excel to a webpage field though if i directly hard code and send it works perfectly

i used this excel command to read and it didnt work while the rest of the fields work perfectly
Local $Read4 = _Excel_RangeRead($oWorkbook, Default, "B33") ; URL of document from Excel
sleep (13000)

the URL in the excel cell B33 is - https://lms.xxxxxxx.net:443/VX-LMS-PROD/ViewDocExternally/ViewDocumentDetails.aspx?DevId=RGV2LTE4ODEucGRm-rImCg7x6Cks=&&Id=MTg4MQ==-ePsTeDP0ykU=&&UserId=30&&DocNo=UUFNLVBBTS0wMDEtMDAwMS4wNw==-

However if i paste directly using send command hard coded it works
send ("https://lms.xxxxxxx.net:443/VX-LMS-PROD/ViewDocExternally/ViewDocumentDetails.aspx?DevId=RGV2LTE4ODEucGRm-rImCg7x6Cks=&&Id=MTg4MQ==-ePsTeDP0ykU=&&UserId=30&&DocNo=UUFNLVBBTS0wMDEtMDAwMS4wNw==-")

Comment: Could it be how the url is formatted inside the excel document cell? Or something simple like an extra space somewhere in the cell that needs trimming.

Comment: thanks i did verify them and it seems okay. I also removed the hyperlink and tried parsing at free text. Looks like the read command has a limitation. I also tried with a long wait time